# Interrupt Service Routine

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling, isr

I studied that we can not really tamper the interrupt vector table but what happens when we install a new device driver in our computer,how does its address get stored in interrupt vector table?

Comment: Which platform and operating is this? It's going to be very different between x86 and ARM/Linux and Windows for example. Every operating system has their own ways of handling interrupts.

Comment: This is in general regarding an operating system,not specific to a particular operating system.